# Expectation and Variance of Simple Random Sampling without Replacement

Tags: self-study, variance, sampling

[image]

The first part is easy since I can say that $E(Z_i)$ has the same distribution as $E(Z_1)$.

However, how do I do this for $E(Z_{i}^2)$?

I know that for sampling without replacement there is a covariance term but again am not sure how to calculate this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $Z_i$ has the same distribution as $Z_1$, which is exactly what you would get from a sample *with replacement* from $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$.

Comment: You need to add the self study tag and you may get other hints like Bill Huber gave.

Comment: This is a finite probability sampling world. Any expectation you derive must have ${N \choose m}$ in the denominator as the number of possible samples. If you are getting anything else, you are hardly on the right track.